# Picasso does not call onBitmapLoaded for the first time

Tags: android, picasso

Picasso does not call `onBitmapLoaded` for the first time ,if you know, please tell me

```
        txtView = (TextView) centerRelative.getChildAt(i);
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(file[i-4]).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        txtView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap));
//                      Not executing for the first time

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
//                      executing for the first time
                    }
                });

Target target = new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        txtView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap));
                        logd("onBitmapLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                };
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(file[i-4]).into(target);
```

Comment: Did you try adding a Log inside it, or your TextView?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:** You have to make some changes here:

Instead of writing:

```
new Target() {...}
```

inside your `into(..)`, you must create a global object of `Target` class. Do not make it local object as it may be garbage collected. So,

**Step1:**

Make a Global object:

```
Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        ....
    }
    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        ....
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        ....
    }
};
```

**Finally**, Use that Target In your `into(...)`:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(file[i-4]).into(target);
```

Try it, Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you you have any error, or just nothing happens? Put up a log now and check please.

Comment: first time call onPrepareLoad,go to anthoner activity,then go back call onBitmapLoaded

Comment: You mean to say that `onBitmapLoaded` is not called at all? untill I come back?

Comment: Okay, Can you show the code where you have tried my solution? Pls edit in the question

Comment: @initialise Please comment your older code from your program.

Comment: This is not correct: `logd("onBitmapLoaded");` You must write like `Log.d("Log","onBitmapLoaded");` Try this and check.

Comment: private void logd(String msg) {
  Log.d(TAG, msg);
 }            it is my log

Comment: Alright my bad.. @initialise add a tag to your textview like this: `textview.setTag(target)` after the target object. and try.

Comment: You can finally try this: [GitHub Link](https://gist.github.com/dominicthomas/d9123f0f18fa05422e52755c30d9e2ba) @initialise I have upvoted your question for others to focus on it..